# Issue in SharePoint Online Authentication for Windows Phone 8.1 Application

Tags: authentication, sharepoint, windows-phone-8.1

I am using the SharePoint Online Client Components (as in below link) to authenticate SharePoint in my Windows Phone 8.1 Application.
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42038
When I try to run my Windows Phone 8.1 Application on Windows Phone Emulator, Authentication works like a charm. But when I deploy the same application to a Windows Phone 8.1 device and try to authenticate SharePoint, I get the following exception:
"Identity Client Runtime Library (IDCRL) encountered an error while talking to the partner STS.".
Note: I am using the following three DLLs
-   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Portable.dll
- Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.Portable.dll
- Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.WindowsPhone.dll

I can NOT use the following two DLLs because there is no option to use SecureString class in Window Phone 8.1 Application, which is consumed by SharePointOnlineCredentials class constructor as one of the parameter. It's anyhow not present in System.Security namespace.
- Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll
- Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll

Please suggest me something. :-(

Code as follows:

```
public static void setContext(string SharePointWebUrl)
    {            
        using (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext _context = new ClientContext(SharePointWebUrl))
        {
            try
            {
                var onlineCredentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(UserName, Password);

                _context.Credentials = onlineCredentials;
                _context.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.Default;                    

                _web = _context.Web;
                _site = _context.Site;
                _context.Load(_web);
                _context.Load(_site);
                _context.ExecuteQueryAsync();

                Utility.isAuthenticated = true;
            }
            catch(Exception ex1)
            {
                Utility.isAuthenticated = false;   
            }
        }
    }
```